# What is that worker means in Azure databricks cluster?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Actually my question is about Azure Databricks pricing. 1st lets see an example that given by Microsoft how billing works.

[image]

1st question is what does that `10` instance means? (10 cluster or 10 workers)
here they multiply price/hour by that `10` instance.

Lets see my cluster configuration.

[image]

In this cluster configuration instance has 14 GB Memory with 4 Cores and .75 Databricks Unit.
lets see another cluster with same configuration just add one more workers.

[image]

Here I just add one more workers and it seems like now we have 28 GB Memory with 8 Cores and 1.5 Databricks Unit.

Ok! I select DS3_v2 worker that's actual price given by Microsoft is $0.709/hours.

[image]

So my final question is are my cost gonna multiply by number of workers?

Like, If I use 2workers then my cost will be 2*$0.709/hours.

or    If I use 1workers then my cost will be $0.709/hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be 10 workers, in your example (not 10 clusters). You are being billed for compute resources you use, not for clusters (because cluster can have many vms)

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41 , I got my 1st answer, whats about my 2nd question? can you please clear that one too.

Comment: well yes, each worker costs money. if 1 workers costs X, 3  workers would cost x * 3 = 3x